# MVC 5 Razor for loop not rendering HiddenFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new learning MVC 5 and I'm out of ideas on this one. I have a Razor view that won't render an @Html.HiddenFor inside a for loop enclosed by an if statement. I also tried removing the for loop, leaving just the if statement, and it still won't render. If I remove both, it does render properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the abbreviated code -- the model's `SelectedFields` list is populated in the controller:

Models:

```
public class MaintModel
{
    public List<SourceField> SelectedFields{ get; set; }
}

public class SourceField
{       
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private int columnOrder;
    public int ColumnOrder
    {
        get { return columnOrder; }
        set { columnOrder = value; }
    }
}
```

Razor code:

```
@using TOTestMgmt
@model TOTestMgmt.Models.MaintModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertDataSet", "DataSetMaint", FormMethod.Post))
{
    if (Model != null && Model.SelectedFields!= null)
    {                           
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedFields.Count; i++)
        {
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InsertDataSetSelFields[i].Id, new { id = "kevtest1" })
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InsertDataSetSelFields[i].ColumnOrder, new { id = "kevtest2" })
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DataSetSource, new { id = "DataSetSourceHidden1" })                
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: You loop is for the collection property `SelectedFields`, but your trying to generate controls for another collection property `InsertDataSetSelFields`. And you generating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes. Not clear what it is that you trying to achieve.

Comment: Apologies...InsertDataSetSelFields is supposed to be SelectedFields (I changed the name to be easier to read but forgot those two).  There was only one item in the list when I tested this so no duplicates -- previously, I was appending the i var onto the end of the id to be sure it was unique but still didn't work. I'm trying to post a Collection of my SourceField class to the controller when the form is submitted.

Comment: If its really `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedFields[i].Id)` then it will work fine assuming your post method has parameter `MaintModel model` (and do not override the default `id` attribute, and since `DataSetSource` is not a collection property, do not put it inside the loop)

Comment: But what is the point of this anyway - why would you degrade performance by sending a whole lot of extra html to the view and then posting it all back  unchanged (and opening yourself up to overposting attacks)

Comment: I had this working a better way with Javascript but it had one problem I couldn't figure out (I posted this as a separate question), so I was trying to learn an alternate way of posting a collection -- using this link [c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection)

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.HiddenFor` works only with current page model. I mean

`@model TOTestMgmt.Models.MaintModel`

Also I've change logic for generating id attribute because Id attribute must be unique on page.

```
    @using TOTestMgmt
    @model TOTestMgmt.Models.MaintModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertDataSet", "DataSetMaint", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        if (Model != null && Model.SelectedFields!= null)
        {                           
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedFields.Count; i++)
            {
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.SelectedFields[i].Id, new { id = "kevtest" + i })
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.SelectedFields[i].ColumnOrder, new { id = "kevtestColumn" + i }))                
            }
        }                
    }
```

Comment: I made these changes and they still don't render. Can you think of anything else?

Comment: Try to figure out if `Model != null && Model.SelectedFields!= null && Model.SelectedFields.Count != 0` using debug tools.